# How do I make this code more manageable audio for collisions?

Tags: c#, optimization, audio, refactoring, unity-game-engine

I'm just looking for any recomendations that would make this code better. If I go ahead in this manner is going to be a huge bit of code which I think is avoidable but the way to do this is beyond me right now. This going to grow out of control very quickly.

```
public enum PhysicMaterialType
{
    SoundFailure = 0,

    AsteroidBall,

    BalloonRubber
}

public void PlaySoundBasedOnCollision ( PhysicMaterialType phyMatA, PhysicMaterialType phyMatB )
{
    switch ( phyMatA )
    {
        case PhysicMaterialType.AsteroidBall:
            {
                CheckAsteroidBallCollision ( phyMatB );

                break;
            }
        case PhysicMaterialType.BalloonRubber:
            {
                CheckBalloonRubberCollision ( phyMatB );

                break;
            }
   }

}

void CheckAsteroidBallCollision ( PhysicMaterial phyMatB )
{
    switch ( phyMatB )

    {
        case PhysicMaterialType.AsteroidBall:
            {
                //Play AsteroidAsteroidBallSound

                break;
            }
        case PhysicMaterialType.BalloonRubber:

            {
                break;
            }
   }
}
```

Comment: What did you want to happen if `phyMatA` is an AsteroidBall and `phyMatB` is a BalloonRubber? (or vice-versa) Do you only have a sound play if they're both the same type?

Comment: That's just a short example, I have around 15 materials at the moment which can all collide with each other and can all play sounds. Though if you swap the order of phyMatB hitting phyMatA it will play the same sound as phyMatA hitting phyMatB.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to have a lot of types, and the expected collision sounds between different types must be handled in a variety of ways, consider deriving a class from PhysicMaterial for each type you're going to implement. Define a public method in the derived classes to handle determining which sound to play - pass the type of the 2nd object to this method.  Like this:

```
class PhysicMaterial
{
   public virtual string GetCollisionSound (PhysicMaterialType targetType)
   {
       // define default behavior here, if derived class doesn't need to do anything special
   }
}

class AsteroidBall : PhysicMaterial
{
   public override string GetCollisionSound (PhysicMaterialType targetType)
   {
       ...
   }
}

class BalloonRubber: PhysicMaterial
{
   public override string GetCollisionSound (PhysicMaterialType targetType)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

Return whatever data type is most suitable to your scenario.